# Regex capture part of text or all text depending on conditions

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Hi guys I am working on some regex to extract the FirstName and first letter of LastName from an account field, only if the account is a human account. Otherwise, if it is a service account I want to capture the full text in the same capturing group where I'd capture the FirstName.

Sounds simple enough but I am working with a naming convention that is not as well defined as I'd like which makes things hard.
Here is the regex I have put together so far.

```
^((-?)(admin|top)-|ADMIN: )?(?<FirstName>[^\n]+?)(?(?= \w* ) (?<MiddleName>\w*)|(?= ?))(?(?= ) (?<LastName>[A-Z])|$)
```

Below are some examples of account names. I've highlighted with bold the parts that need to be captured by the regex.

- -admin-**JohnS**  (here I want to grab JohnS in the FirstName capturing group)
- admin-**JohnS**
- ADMIN: **John** **S**mith (here the S needs to be captured by the LastName capturing  group)
- -top-**JohnS**
- top-**JohnS**
- **John** **S**mith
- **John** Peter **S**mith
- **-service-something**
- **service-something**
- **-svc-something**
- **svc-something**
- **svc.something**
- **SERVICE: Something**
- **someServiceAccount**

The regex works great for almost all the occasions except for "SERVICE: Something" where "SERVICE:" is captured by the FirstName group and "S" is captured by the LastName capturing group. What can I do to fix this and capture all the text? I have tried a few things with negative lookaheads but didn't get me anywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the environment? Regex syntax and semantics vary widely.

Comment: If this is for PCRE (e.g. PHP) have a try with [this variant](https://regex101.com/r/iAnpbe/1).

Comment: @bobblebubble That's very close to what I'm trying to achieve. Only problem with your regex is that in the case of "John Peter Smith" the "S" in Smith is captured by a different capturing group than the "S"s captured in the other formats i.e. "John Smith".

Ideally this should be captured by the same group as I need to extract this uniformly for all formats for use later.

Comment: @Kstr Right, I think you can make the middlename group optional and use a lookahead inside this group that it can only match before the last word. See [this updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/iAnpbe/2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use:

```
^(?:-?(?i:admin(?:: |-)|top-))?(?<FirstName>[^\s:]+(?:: .*)?)(?: (?<MiddleName>\w+(?= \w)))?(?: (?<LastName>[A-Z]))?
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `-?(?i:admin(?:: |-)|top-)` Match optional `-` and either `admin:`  or `admin-` or `top-` case insensitive
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional
- `(?<FirstName>[^\s:]+(?:: .*)?)` Match the first name consisting of any non whitespace char except `:` and then optionally match `:`  and the rest of the line
- `(?: (?<MiddleName>\w+(?= \w)))?` Match only the middle name if there is a following part with a space and a word char
- `(?: (?<LastName>[A-Z]))?` Optionally match a space and the first char of the last name

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A3Veij/1)

Comment: This one almost works. I made a small correction to make "admin" case insensitive.

^(?:-?(?i:admin(?:: |-)|top-))?(?<FirstName>[^\s:]+(?:: .*)?)(?: (?<MiddleName>\w+(?= \w)))?(?: (?<LastName>[A-Z]))?

if you change your answer I'll mark your answer correct.

Comment: @Kstr I have updated it.

Comment: This looks good, doesn't it!